# Display only matched string with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, match

I have a file that I want to match that looks like the following:

```
...
new VideoInfo(6, VideoType.Flash, 270, false, AudioType.Mp3, 64, AdaptiveType.None),
new VideoInfo(13, VideoType.Mobile, 0, false, AudioType.Aac, 0, AdaptiveType.None),
new VideoInfo(17, VideoType.Mobile, 144, false, AudioType.Aac, 24, AdaptiveType.None),
... [a few hundred more entries like these]
```

And I have the following regex pattern to match the first number:

```
grep "new VideoInfo(.*," VideoInfo.cs
```

The trouble is, grep emits the entire line that was matched instead of just `6 13 17 ...`.

How can I get it to echo only the matched results?

---

**EDIT:** I have trailing whitespace in front of each `new VideoInfo ...` line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using grep

If your grep supports the `-P` option for perl-style regex:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=new VideoInfo\()[^,]*' file
6
13
17
```

`(?<=pattern)` is a look-behind.  Thus, the above matches on the regex `[^,]*` but only if that regex is preceded by `new VideoInfo\(`.

#### Using sed

sed is a good match to this problem:

```
$ sed -nr 's/[[:space:]]*new VideoInfo\(([^,]*),.*/\1/p' file
6
13
17
```

#### Using bash

```
$ re='new VideoInfo\(([^,]*)'
$ while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done< file
6
13
17
```

Comment: `sed`: It did better than the first `grep -o` solution, but it seems to be echoing trailing whitespace ahead of the matches.

Comment: @JamesKo Easy enough: the sed solution now removes leading whitespace.  (I didn't address that earlier because none of your examples showed leading whitespace.)

Answer (score 5):

This will do:

```
grep -o pattern file
```

`-o` is for only match.

---

Your regex won't do what you want. Use Perl regex instead:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\bnew VideoInfo\().*?(?=,)" file
```

`(?<=pattern)` is look behind and `(?=pattern)` is look ahead, both are excluded in the matched string in `grep`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `-o` (*only-matching*) and `-P` (*Perl-regexp*) parameters.

```
grep -oP '\bnew VideoInfo\(\K\d+' VideoInfo.cs
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word char and a non-word character.(vice-versa) . `\K` is same as positive look-behind where the lookbehinds won't support any quantifiers but `\K` does. ie, we may use `foo[^,]*,\K\d+` but we can't do `(?<=foo[^,]*,)\d+` because lookbehinds won't allow quantifiers `*`, `?`, `+` to be present inside them (PCRE only).

**or**

```
grep -oP '^\s*new VideoInfo\(\K[^,]*' VideoInfo.cs
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about the `\K` flag.